# Помогите решить задачку по java

Tags: java

Задание к выполнению (по вариантам).
Разработать простой класс на основе заданной структуры данных, включающего в
себя набор функций-аксессоров вида (get, set).

Спортсмен (ФИО, год рождения, разряд, количество лет в спорте)

Comment: Вроде как тебе к выполнению. Выполняй.

Comment: Как правило вопрос должен подразумевать что-то конкретное. Что вы что-то попытались сделать и у вас не получилось. Задание к выполнению - это не вопрос, а задание к выполнению, которое вы должны хотя бы попытаться выполнить сами. Скажите, в чём у вас конкретно проблема, чтобы можно было конкретно ответить.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подскажу, в какую сторону двигаться. Класс должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
паблик класс Спортсмен {
    // приватное поле класса
    прийват Строка фио;

    // конструктор по умолчанию
    паблик Спортсмен() {
    }

    // геттер
    паблик Строка гетФио() {
        ретурн зыс.фио;
    }

    // сеттер
    паблик войд сетФио(Строка фио) {
        зыс.фио = фио;
    }
}
```